# performance concerns when storing log records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have setup a 15 min cron job to monitor 10+ websites' performance (all hosted on different servers). Every 15 mins I will check if the server is up/down, the response time in ms etc.

I would like to save these information into MySQL instead of a log.txt file, so that it can be easily retrieve, query and analysis. (ie. the server performance on x day or x month or server performance between x and y days)

here is my table's going to look like:

---

id     website_ip     recorded_timestamp response_time_in_ms website_status

---

If I insert a new entry for each website, every day I'll have 1440 records for each website (15 x 4 x 24), then for 10 websites it will be 14400 records every day!!

so, I'm thinking of creating only 1 entry each hour / website. In this way instead of creating 14400 records every day, I'll only have 24 x 10 = 240 records every day for 10 websites.

But still, it's not perfect, what if I want to know keep the records for the whole year? then I'll have 87600 records for 365 years for 10 websites.

is 87600 records alot? my biggest concern is the difference between the server local time and client local time. How to improve the design without screwing up the accuracy and timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long or too short for a comment.  The simple answer to your question is "no".

No, 87,600 records is *not* a lot of records.  In fact, your full data with 5,256,000 records per year is not that much.  It could be a lot of data if you had really wide records, but your record is at most a few tens of bytes.  The resulting table would still have less than a gigabyte per year.  Not very much at all, really.

Databases are designed to have big tables.  You have the opportunity to do things to speed your queries on the log files.  The most obvious is to create indexes on columns that would often be used for selection purposes.  Another opportunity is to use partitioning to break up the storage of the tables into separate "files" (technically table spaces), so queries require less I/O.

You may want to periodically summarize more recent records and store the results in summary tables for your most common queries.  However, that level of detail is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: thanks Gordon. I was thinking about creating a summary tables. However having different client's local timezone make it hard to display accurate statistics. Let's say if website A is down from Aug 5 00:00:01 GMT 0 to Aug 5 04:00:00 (4 hours of downtime), however if I or someone who is from a different timezone (GMT + 4), then according to my timezone Aug has no downtime.

Comment: @Josh . . . That is another question, but such time zone issues are a pain.  Especially in this case, where the data may be stored in one time zone, the user in another, and the business rules may specify a third (the user and their business may not be co-located).  The real problem is specifying the rules that define such a simple concept as "August".